# dependsl not implemented

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

detail:

```
adminyin@adminyin-System:~$ cd catkin_ws/src/
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ ls
beginner_tutorials  CMakeLists.txt
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ rospack dependsl beginner_tutorials
[rospack] Error: command dependsl not implemented
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ rospack depends
depends            depends-indent     depends-msgsrv     depends-on1
depends1           depends-manifests  depends-on         depends-why
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ rospack depends beginner_tutorials
[rospack] Error: no such package beginner_tutorials
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ cd ..
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws$ . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws$ cd src/
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ ls
beginner_tutorials  CMakeLists.txt
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ rospack depends beginner_tutorials 
cpp_common
rostime
roscpp_traits
roscpp_serialization
genmsg
genpy
message_runtime
catkin
```

computer environment:

```
Linux adminyin-System 3.16.0-57-generic #77~14.04.1-Ubuntu
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224845/dependsl-not-implemented/) by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ rospack dependsl beginner_tutorials
> ```

```
[rospack] Error: command dependsl not implemented
```

It's `depends1` (one), not `dependsl` (el).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2016-01-22**:
Great, you are right, thank you!